# Filtering rows from DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, dataview

I have a `DataTable` with 1000000 records. I am filtering records from `DataTable`. I have used various methods for filtering:

- `DataTable.Select()`
- Linq to DataTable
- `DataView.RowFilter`

After filtering records, binding the resulting records (approx. 1000 records) to a ListBox.

The whole process is taking much time. I analyzed the code and found that filtering is taking much time. The whole process should be done in milliseconds. For each filtering I can't hit on server to fetch records.

Please suggest.

```
//using dataTable
DataRow[] dr = dtData.Select("i_pernr=" + perno + "");
dr.CopyToDataTable(dtTemp,LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);

//using DataView
dtData.DefaultView.RowFilter = "i_pernr=" + perno ;
dtTemp = dtData.DefaultView.ToTable();

//Using Linq
IEnumerable<DataRow> query = from m in dtData.AsEnumerable()
                             where m["i_pernr"] == perno
                             select m;
query.CopyToDataTable(dtTemp,LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);
```

Comment: Unless you provide your code I doubt you get any useful help here

Comment: _Lakh_ is not a number outside of, what, India?

Comment: I am using this code.And it is taking approx 1 sec time.

Comment: What about this : List<DataRow> query =  (from m in dtData.AsEnumerable()
                                      where m["i_pernr"] == perno
                                       select m).ToList();

Comment: The best solution would be to retrieve only those 1000 rows you need to display in the first place .....

Comment: @jdweng I dont think this will make any difference, While using Linq I am already returning a list of DataRow.

Comment: @marc_s This filtering is used in an application where around 6000 users will be using it at a time. So, for each filtering I cannot hit on server to fetch only matching records.

Comment: Have you actually tried and compared the time needed? Retrieving 1 million rows for each of those 6000 users and then filtering seems like a pretty inefficient approach, in my opinion....

Comment: Want to compare IEnumerable with Enumerable.

Answer (score 0):

If you really feel that filtering at the source isn't possible (SQL Server is much better at selecting records) you can only speed up the selection operation by setting the [`PrimaryKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.primarykey(v=vs.110).aspx) for the `DataTable`.

```
dtData.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dtData.Columns["i_pernr"]};
```

Notice that you can have multiple columns as primarykey columns. You'll have to add as much as needed to make guarantee the datarows you add/have are unique.

I've used the following test rig:

```
var dtTemp = new DataTable();
dtTemp.Columns.Add("i_pernr", typeof(int));
dtTemp.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));

var dtData = new DataTable();
dtData.Columns.Add("i_pernr", typeof(int));
dtData.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
dtData.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { 
    dtData.Columns["i_pernr"], 
    dtData.Columns["name"]
    };

var rnd = new Random();
for(int r = 1; r<1000000; r++)
{
    var row =dtData.NewRow();
    row[0] = rnd.Next(1000);
    row[1]= String.Format("the lazy fox jumps again {0}",rnd.Next(10000000)) ;
    try
    {
       dtData.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    catch
    {
       // Hey, for testing this is fine ...
    }
}
```

This loads a datatable with enough rows to test the effect of having or not having a PrimaryKey it the stopwatch:

```
dtData.Rows.Count.Dump("rows");

var perno = rnd.Next(1000).ToString();

var sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
DataRow[] dr = dtData.Select("i_pernr=" + perno + "");
dr.CopyToDataTable(dtTemp,LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);
sw.Stop();
sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.Dump("elapsed");
sw.ElapsedTicks.Dump("ticks");
```

This output in LinqPad when using the PrimaryKey:

```
elapsed:    0 
ticks:  5,371
```

Without the primarykey the results are:

```
elapsed:     2,444 
ticks:   7,541,415
```